# When switching to zabbix 6.2.2, how do we have to change password setting?

Tags: mysql, zabbix

**Additional info**

Now using zabbix 6.2.2 I noticed that `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql/create.sql.gz` no longer exists. After some googling I found `zabbix-sql-scripts`. Unsure what to import from the new folder `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sql-scripts` I picked `./mysql/server.sql.gz` because we use `MariaDB`.
This indeed set up the database zabbix.users.

**Actual question**

However: In the old zabbix version we ran `update users set passwd=md5('PASSWORD') where alias='Admin'` on `zabbix.users`. Alias doesn't exist anymore so I switched to `update users set passwd=md5('PASSWORD') where username='Admin'`. That seemed to do the trick, but **didn't**. While the command runs without error, the password is not correctly set.

Even though I set `login_user: Admin` and `login_password: PASSWORD` ansible fails to connect. This does not happen if the password is not set and standard "zabbix" is used.

Why is setting the password no longer working?

I am still very new to zabbix, but the project worked before on an older zabbix version just importing aforementioned `create.sql.gz`.

Comment: `but_why.gif` ...no seriously, if you need the change 1 user password, use the web interface. If you need to change all passwords, use API `user.update(object/array users)`.

Comment: This is a setup done by ansible for a cluster. It is not feasible to do this in the web interface. I don't know much about the API. But that might have worked, too. This question is no longer necessary. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646306/how-escape-random-string-for-linux-shell-to-update-mysql-datase-entry-using-ansi?noredirect=1#comment130051730_73646306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since 5.0 Zabbix switched from md5 hashing algorithm to bcrypt:
> https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1898 Since then, on the
> first log in after upgrade all md5 hashes are converted to bcrypt by
> Frontend automatically.

https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/410430-reset-admin-password-for-zabbix-lts-5-0

Therefore I needed to use `bcrypt` instead of `md5` which I did using the inbuilt ansible command `password_hash` combined with `passlib`: [How escape random string for linux shell to update mysql datase entry using ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646306/how-escape-random-string-for-linux-shell-to-update-mysql-datase-entry-using-ansi?noredirect=1#answer-73647550)

Answer (score 1):

In Zabbix 6.2, md5 is not used anymore and field "alias" was renamed in "surname" so to solve this, please use the following MySQL command:

```
UPDATE zabbix.users AS a INNER JOIN zabbix.users AS b ON b.username='guest' SET a.passwd = b.passwd;
```

This will set the Admin password same as Guest (without password)
Then you can log in into the Zabbix web interface as Admin (without password)
Please do not forget to change your password on first log in.

Thanks