# How escape random string for linux shell to update mysql datase entry using ansible?

Tags: shell, ansible, bcrypt

For a specific case I need to `echo` a random string returned by ansible's function `password_hash` that contains multiple random `$` signs (encryption method `bcrypt`). The echoed string is then piped into the next command.

Ideally I would just escape the entire string. If that is not possible, I would like to escape all `$` signs. How is that possible? If there is an ansible native command that automatically escapes a variable, that would be fine, too.

**Full task if needed**

```
- name: Update Admin password
  shell: "echo \"update users set passwd={{ zabbix_conf.admin_password|password_hash('bcrypt') }} where username='Admin'\" | mysql --user={{ zabbix_conf.db_user}} --password={{ zabbix_conf.db_password }} zabbix"
```

Currently doesn't work as expected, because the `$` signs affect the echo to be empty.

Comment: You could probably test including single quotes `passwd='{{ zabbix_conf.admin_password | password_hash('bcrypt') }}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible already has an inbuilt command for executing mysql queries called `mysql_query`. Therefore one can simply do:

```
- name: Update Admin password
      mysql_query:
        login_db: "{{ zabbix_conf.db }}"
        login_user: "{{ zabbix_conf.db_user}}"
        login_password: "{{ zabbix_conf.db_password }}"
        query: "update users set passwd='{{ zabbix_conf.admin_password|password_hash('bcrypt') }}' where username='Admin'"
```

That way you don't need to escape anything and it looks much cleaner, too.

In case someone wants to reproduce this: Ansible requires the installation of `passlib` to `password_hash` `bycrypt`.